# Parsing JSON in VBA strange object being returned

Tags: json, excel, vba

I'm writing an excel program which reads a JSON string from a web service. The string contains the contents of a database view. Using some answers from this website i've been able to convert the string into an object using a script control and the evaluate funcion

```
set sc = new ScriptControl
sc.Eval(sJSONString)
```

However when I examine what has been produced in the object it is arranged extremely oddly. The data has been arranged into both non-continuous (note the 99) indexes and Items in the same object. Can anyone shed any light on what is happening please? (Please do not suggest using non standard VBA libraries, I can't)

[image]

Comment: Hard to guess without seeing the actual JSON you're working with.

Comment: After a bit of testing it seems that's how any  js array will display in the Watch window: each element is listed both under its index in the array (0, 1, etc), and as the "Item1", "Item2", etc version. The "index" version is no-contiguous because the "expression" ordering is "asciibetical", not numeric.

Comment: That's excellent Tim, Could you write than as an answer please and i'll accept it. If you could show me how to iterate through it you would earn my extra gratitude! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of testing it seems that's how any js array will display in the Watch window: each element is listed both under its index in the array (0, 1, etc), and as the "Item1", "Item2", etc version.

The "index" version is non-contiguous because the "expression" ordering is "asciibetical", not numeric.

Here's a rough example of parsing and iterating an array:

```
Sub Tester()
Dim sc, o, json, n, i

    Set sc = New ScriptControl
    sc.Language = "Jscript"

    json = "{data:[{'prop1':'val1','prop2':'val2'}," & _
           "  {'prop1':'val3','prop2':'val4'}," & _
           "  {'prop1':'val5','prop2':'val6'}]}"

    sc.ExecuteStatement "var o = eval((" & json & "));"
    sc.AddCode "function getCount(){return o.data.length;}"
    sc.AddCode "function getItem(i){return o.data[i-1]};"

    n = sc.Eval("getCount()") '--> 3
    For i = 1 To n
        Set o = sc.Eval("getItem(" & i & ")")
        Debug.Print o.prop1, o.prop2
    Next i



End Sub
```